# How widely used is Asterisk PBX?

Tags: asterisk, performance

I have a big final project coming up in my university CS degree and my project is a vague 'performance monitoring of a server' idea. My college mentor is big into telco's and netts and comms and I also have a company mentor from a big netts&comms MNC.

We have this idea of using Asterisk PBX and creating some form of plugin or add on that monitors stats of servers, call stats, call quality stats etc (Still very vague and in brainstorming phase)

Anyway, what I want to know is if Asterisk PBX is a widely used software in the industry? Basically, I want a project that has some form of 'value' and would look good at the end and be interesting.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

My decidedly non-scientific survey suggests that asterisk is used VERY widely under the hood of many modern PBX devices (i.e. not Avaya, Nortel, and other old-guard), but they usually wrap the asterisk service in vendor-specific management layers.

Perhaps someone else will have better data for you, but this has been my observation over the last 5 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Asterisk used not so much. But asterisk inside other packages/distribution/firmware is very common. Most common distribution are Elastix and Trixbox. Both state few millions of install each.

Also there are alot of installation that was "rebranded" and say it not asterisk, but some observation(common issues and errors, bugs etc) say that it still asterisk, just under other name.

Reasons for that

1) Asterisk is first and most known opensource softswitch, so source for it availible more then 10 years.

2) People are lazy and prefer use some other code, even if have task create something new under other license.

But you need understand, that if you need big telco project, you have find some other staff. Asterisk never was designed to be under hi load and work not excelent in telco. For big number of channels/hi value see itel's SER  or openser/kamailio/opensips routes.